# How to enable scattered mode in DPDK?

Tags: networking, dpdk

I set the dataroom of the mbuf from 2048 to 64B. To receive large packets（>64B） with a 64B size dataroom mbuf, DPDK reminds me that I need to enable scattered mode. So how can I enable scattered mode?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rx scatter can be enabled at the stage when [`rte_eth_dev_configure()`](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__ethdev_8h.html#a1a7d3a20b102fee222541fda50fd87bd) is invoked. To do that, one should pass flag `RTE_ETH_RX_OFFLOAD_SCATTER` via [`dev_conf.rx_mode.offloads`](https://doc.dpdk.org/api/structrte__eth__rxmode.html#a6cfe3b3ee46e9a8b8c62a64294b0b564), with `dev_conf` being passed by pointer as the last argument to `rte_eth_dev_configure()`.

To check the feature with [testpmd](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/), one can pass command-line argument [`--enable-scatter`](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/testpmd_app_ug/run_app.html#testpmd-command-line-options).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But, I don't fully understand. It means that I should modify my application codes,instead of the DPDK drivers? Is there some config files where I can set "scatter = y" to enable the scattered mode?

Comment: The question does not specify the application. Is it a custom one? If so, then yes, the application code should be modified to *request* Rx scatter from the driver. This request is done by passing flag `RTE_ETH_RX_OFFLOAD_SCATTER` to the driver during device configuration stage, as explained in the answer. That's it. To see examples, one can `grep -r 'RTE_ETH_RX_OFFLOAD_SCATTER' ./app` inside DPDK repo directory.